# distinguish between local scope and global scope variables with same name in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

how to distinguish between local scope and global scope variables with same name in "swift" (and in "objective-c")

For eg:

```
var a = 10
for i in 1...10 {
  var a = 20
  a = 40
}
```

in this code snippet, how can I save 40 to the global variable "a" ? 
Sorry if it's a duplicate question.

**Edit**

Changing any variable name is obviously possible, but I want to know if there any way to do this.

Comment: Why don't you just declare the variables as having different names?

Comment: Obviously it's easy, but I just want to know if there any possible ways to do this like "this" operator

Answer (score 5):

Its a bad practice as **Paulw11** has mentioned. But actually you can do it.

`The top level namespaces are modules.By default, app is a module and hence a namespace.This namespace's name is the name of the app.`

**So you can access it as:-**

```
    <ModuleName>.a = 40
```

Here `ModuleName` will be the name of your app.